# Subtracting minimum and maximum data from the group in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, extract

I have a problem with extracting the data from dataset. In my company project has some processes, which are grouped in categories. So I have one project which has many processes grouped. On the basis of column "D" I would like to get the first data and the last date from every kind of category. For example, for project 20.28 I would like to have start date from row 5 and finish date from row 4. I hundreds of projects divided into categories so making it manually isn't and option here. Below is a sample.
[Sample data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bIPI.png)

Comment: Have you tried to create a pivot?

Comment: I was trying without success, but after your recommendation I have sat one more time and it works! Thank you for a tip

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution based on consecutive filters with formulas. If this works to you I'll post here the steps.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdxMGRDl_sV5wRmqIFouDQs8L43LVxgi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I dont understand how it works, but due to my curiosity I would liek to get familiqar with this solutions, seems quite interesting

Comment: I am familiar with this method. It is about abstrating small problems of the big problem and using each filter as a resource for the following.